# Python viewplane

Tags: python, add-on

I have a question on getting the mouse coordinates (in 3d space) when I click in the 3d view.

I have a draw handler in a modal operator (POST_VIEW) and I want to get the mouse cursor x, y vertex and the 3rd vertex should be on the current viewplane.

Do you have a Python example?

Comment: See the _`Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Modal Draw`_ template.

Answer (score 1):

**[bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy_extras.view3d_utils.html?highlight=bpy_extras%20view3d_utils#bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d)**

> Return a 3d location from the region relative 2d coords, aligned with
>   depth_location.

Here is the code:

```
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_location_3d
...
x, y = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
region = context.region
rv3d = context.space_data.region_3d

# this is the vector
loc = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (x, y), (0, 0, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: What context do I need to obtain 'context.space_data.region_3d'.  My console output:  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'region_3d'